# Is it possible to use the Google Translate api with iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-translate

How do I use the google translate API with iOS 6.0? I have tried googling the documentation and tried to research it, but I can't find anything that is updated since google made the api to be no longer free.

The only thing I have been able to find was this, but it didn't really help much because I need to use the api key that I have, but I have no idea how to.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1448/how-to-translate-text-with-google-translate-and-json-on-the-iphone

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but at a guess it's because the question is extremely broad — making it not all that good a fit for the Q&A format of StackOverflow — and because you don't make it particularly clear what you've already tried and what results you found.

Comment: I updated it with a link to the only thing I found for iOS and the api. Does that make it betteR?

Comment: @RobSmith Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

This seems up to date: https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started

(completely meta: Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 23)

Comment: Thanks! I used this URL - NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MYKEY&q=%@&v=1.0&langpair=%@", textEscaped, langStringEscaped]; where MYKEY is my api key, but I get this error.  Connection Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 *bad URL* UserInfo=0x1d5b6370

Comment: I noticed there was a space in the url and now I get response status 0

Comment: Response status 0 and no NSError? Sounds odd.

Comment: I go this which I would assume means the url is working, but that I have reached the limit.{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Once you get your Google key, just plug it into [FGTranslator](https://github.com/gpolak/FGTranslator). Note, generate a "server" key, since the Google Translate API does not currently support iOS keys.

It's just a one-line call to the translate function after that.

```
FGTranslator *translator = [[FGTranslator alloc] initWithGoogleAPIKey:@"your_google_key"];

[translator translateText:@"Bonjour!" 
               completion:^(NSError *error, NSString *translated, NSString *sourceLanguage)
{
    NSLog(@"translated from %@: %@", sourceLanguage, translated);
}];
```